# Catching orientation change in Android activity without touching the layout

Tags: android

In my `Activity` i have `SurfaceView` for displaying camera preview and few control buttons. This `Activity` should have two working cases: the first one, when orientation is landscape and camera preview ratio is set to 4:3, and the second one, when orientation is portrait and the camera preview should be squeare.
What I actually want to do is just to adjust view according to orientation. 
I have already tried to handle orientation changing in my activity by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to my activity description in manifest, but the problem here is even thought `onCreate()` method is not called, activity components are rearranged. I suppose it happens in when I call         `super.onConfigurationChanged(null);` (which I can't avoid, because I will get exception).
So my question is if it is possible at all to achieve the effect I am trying to achieve? Or I have no choice but to have two separate layouts for different orientations and allow activity to be recreated?
[image: This is how my acitivyt look like in portrait mode]
[image: And this is what I get when rotate my device]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without a separate layout for each orientation, you can just subclass `SurfaceView` (or `TextureView`) with a method to adjust the aspect ratio. This is actually the method the Android team uses in the [Camera sample applications](https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/index.html):

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then you don't need to override `onConfigurationChanged`, all you need to do is check the orientation of the device sometime after `onResume`:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    mAutoFitTextureView.setAspectRatio(width, height);
} else {
    mAutoFitTextureView.setAspectRatio(width, width);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Bryan. But this approach supposes that the Activity should be paused and then resumed. Maybe that's no clear from my message, but I need to handle orientation changes when my activity is running and wanna try to achieve effect, when there will be no visible changes except the surface changing it's dimensions and no pauses during work (but I am still not sure if Android SDK have tools for this).